# Execute stored procedure in Azure Data Platform - Post SQL Scripts

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

Based on the documentation below,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database
[image]

There is a feature to run post SQL script. Would it be possible to run stored procedure from there?

I have tried, it does not seem to be working and currently investigating.

Thanks for your information in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a test to prove that the stored procedure can be called in the Post SQL scripts.

I created two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp](
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [age] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) 


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp_stage](
    id int,
    [name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [age] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

I created a sotred procedure.

```sql
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMergeEmpData]
AS
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.emp ON
   MERGE [dbo].[emp] AS target
   USING [dbo].[emp_stage] AS source
   ON (target.[id] = source.[id])
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET name = source.name,
       age = source.age

    WHEN NOT matched THEN

       
       INSERT (id, name, age)
      VALUES (source.id, source.name, source.age);
    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[emp_stage]
END
```

I will copy the csv file into my Azure SQL staging table `[dbo].[emp_stage]`, then use stored porcedure `[dbo].[spMergeEmpData]` to transfer data from `[dbo].[emp_stage]` to `[dbo].[emp]`.

[image]

Enter the stored procedure name `exec [dbo].[spMergeEmpData]` in the Post SQL scripts field.
[image]

I successfully debugged.
[image]

I can see the data  are all in TABLE `[dbo].[emp]`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Let me try and confirm.

Comment: Thanks. Tested and confirmed. Marked this post as answer. Thanks for your information.